# CSS stylesheets with different titles not applied - even without rel="alternative"

Tags: javascript, css, webkit, w3c

i'd like to have a deeper insight in the following rendering logic:

**None of these stylesheets applied initially:**

```
<link rel="alternate stylesheet" title="x">
<link rel="alternate stylesheet" title="x">
```

**Both stylesheets applied:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" title="x">
<link rel="alternate stylesheet" title="x">
```

**First stylesheet applied:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" title="x">
<link rel="stylesheet" title="y">
// OR
<style title="x"></style>
<style title="y"></style>
```

I understand the first two cases but not the last one - which cost me some time recently. Because if you add two style elements with different titles it creates two CSSStyleSheet objects with different titles. therefore I thought we can identify the CSSStyleSheet by its title and modify its cssRules but the second never got rendered. So in the end I've set the id which you can access trough the ownerNode.id and left away the title - but I'd like to have some more insight why they've implemented this logic...to me two different titles would mean two different stylesheets and therefore that they should be rendered.

Answer (score 0):

See [Correctly Using Titles With External Stylesheets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Correctly_Using_Titles_With_External_Stylesheets) and [Alternative style sheets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Alternative_style_sheets) on MDN or [Alternative Style: Working With Alternate Style Sheets](http://alistapart.com/article/alternate) on A List Apart.

In short, a stylesheet is always one of:

- **Persistent** (no `rel="alternate"`, no `title=""`): always applies to the document.
- **Preferred** (no `rel="alternate"`, with `title="..."` specified): applied by default, but disabled if an alternate stylesheet is selected. **There can only be one preferred stylesheet**, which explains the behavior in your 3rd example.
- **Alternate** (`rel="stylesheet alternate"`, `title="..."` must be specified): disabled by default, can be selected.

Your `document.styleSheets[i].ownerNode.id` solution looks good to me.